# Which scriptures say that eating rice mixed with milk at night increases one's life span while eating curd at night decreases it?

Tags: belief, scripture, brahmins, food

[This](http://brahminrituals.blogspot.in/2011_05_01_archive.html) page makes the following claims:

> The following five things reduce the span of our life viz morning sun
> light falling on our body, the smoke from corpse touching us, love
> making with older woman, drinking turbid water without filtering it,
> **and drinking curd at night**.
>
> The following things increase our life span viz Evening sun light
> falling on our body, The smoke from Homa touching our body, love
> making with woman younger to us, Drinking pure water and **eating rice
> mixed with milk at night.**
>
> [image]

I want to know the scriptural basis for these claims.

Comment: I have not read such a text but am told this is according to Ayurveda. Eating solid curds at night is not healthy; diluting the curds with water (to make buttermilk) or eating rice with milk is recommended.

Comment: Good Q. In fact all the 5 matters are separate Qs. I used to think morning sunlight is good. Why don't you make a general title? Just specific to curd actually undervalues the quoted text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are from the [Neeti Saara or Neeti Shastra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neeti_Sastra) written by Baddena. it is one of the widely accepted Subhashitam text especially in South India.

The ślokas are as follows

> बालार्कः प्रेतधूमश्च वृद्धस्त्री पल्वलोदकम् ।
>
> रात्रौ **दध्यन्नभुक्तिश्च** आयुःक्षीणंदिनेदिने ( रोगवृद्धिर्दिनेदिने ) ॥
>
> bālārkaḥ pretadhūmaśca vṛddhastrī palvalodakam ।
>
> rātrau **dadhyannabhuktiśca** āyuḥkṣīṇaṃdinedine ( rogavṛddhirdinedine ) ॥
>
> Morning Sun, smoke from funeral pyre, coitus with (meaning marrying a ) older 
>   woman , muddy water and **eating curd-rice at night** decrease life
>   (increase
>   ill health) day by day.
>
> वृद्धार्को होमधूमश्च बालस्त्री निर्मलोदकम् ।
>
> रात्रौ **क्षीरान्नभुक्तिश्च** आयुर्वृद्धिर्दिनेदिने ॥
>
> vṛddhārko homadhūmaśca bālastrī nirmalodakam ।
>
> rātrau **kṣīrānnabhuktiśca** āyurvṛddhirdinedine ॥
>
> Setting Sun, smoke from Homa (sacrificial pyre),  coitus with (meaning 
>   marrying a ) young woman , pure water and **eating milk rice at
>   night** increase
>   longevity day by day.

It is rice with curd that decreases life. But usual practice is taking butter milk or milk-rice at night.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of the topics (viz-morning sun and smoke out of burning corpse) are mentioned in Manu Smriti itself.

**Although ,not explicitly mentioned as things that reduce lifespan.But mentioned as to be "avoided" none the less**.

Manu Smriti , Chapter 4, verse 69 says:

> 4.69. **The morning sun, the smoke rising from a (burning) corpse,** and a broken seat **must be avoided**. Let him not clip his nails or hair, and
>   not tear his nails with his teeth.

I have also now found the following verse which says that Alakshmi (the deity of misfortune) resides in curds during night. So, it is that's why not recommended to be consumed at night.

> Ill luck (Alakshmi] resides in the shade of a Kapiththa tree during
>   the day, in the mixture of milkcurd and barley powder during the
>   night, and constantly in the kernels of Amalaka fruit.
>
> **Likihta Smriti's last chapter**.