# Scripture(s) saying not to look at the sun during his rising and setting time

Tags: scripture, surya

Consider the [following](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b069.htm) statements of Bhishma from Anusasana Parva of Mahabharata

> **One should never look at the rising sun, nor at the setting sun.** Nor
>   should one look at the sun when he is in eclipse; nor at his image in
>   the water; nor at midday when he is at the meridian.

Does any other scripture(s) support the statement which forbids looking at the sun when it is rising and setting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the Manu Smriti also says the same:

> 4.37. Let him never look at the sun, when he sets or rises, is eclipsed or reflected in water, or stands in the middle of the sky

and, also the Apasthambha Smriti:

> He should avoid looking at the sun as it rises or sets. During the day
>   the sun protects creatures, and during the night, the moon. Therefore,
>   on the night of the new moon he should try his very best to guard
>   himself by keeping himself pure and chaste and by performing rites
>   appropriate for the occasion, for on this night the sun and the moon
>   dwell together.
>
> **Apasthambha Dharma Sutras 1.13.18-20**

So, there will be similar verses in all the Smritis.

From [this page](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200141.html), we can get similar verses from various other Smritis:

> Viṣṇu (7.17, 18).—‘He shall not look at the sun rising,—nor when
>   setting.’
>
> Yājñavalkya (1.137).—‘He shall not look at the sun, nor at a naked
>   woman....’
>
> Pāraskara (2.7.6 ).—‘ He shall not do the following—looking at a
>   water-reservoir, tree-climbing, fruit-gathering, entering a man-hole,
>   public bathing, traversing dangerous situations, looking at the sun,
>   and begging.’
>
> Baudhāyana (2.3.31).—‘He shall not look at the sun at the time of
>   rising or of setting.’
>
> Hārīta (Aparārka, p. 180).—‘He shall not look at the naked man or the
>   naked woman; nor the rising or setting sun and moon

Comment: there are verses which say do not look at rising sun (reduces lifespan), but setting sun is fine (increases life span)

Comment: Why is this forbidden?

Comment: @ram For rising sun i know the verse, given here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15394/4732

Comment: @Wikash_hindu Not sure, .. see the link that I hv added in the answer .. that page has commentary and explanatory notes on the verse

Comment: What if not looking directly, but chanting gayatri with eyes closed, with direction towards sun, during certain instances of sunset, sunrise, my third eye activates, I can see random sanskrit characters in siddham/Tibetean script in blue color(electric aura) in center of yellow, orange background.

Comment: There is no prohibition on chanting Gayatri, prohibition is only on seeing the sun at certain times of the day @Aoi.T_015