# Can one look at the rising and setting sun during Sandhyavandanam?

Tags: surya, sandhyavandanam

[According to scriptures](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/33365/11726), one should not look at the rising and setting sun.

But what about during morning and evening Sandhyavandanam when one faces the sun and meditates on it? Is that the only exception when you can look at the sun?

Comment: yes he can look

Comment: i have read in other place that - rising sun, curd at night, relations with older woman - reduce lifespan, but - setting sun, milk at night, relations with younger woman - increase lifespan. so i'm not sure about not seeing setting sun.

Comment: Both should not be looked at mandheha will come procastination attitude to life will come but mid day soon can be looked. Looking at raising and setting sun is prohibited according to vedic scripture i dont have reference but vedic people follow the pattern like grahana, during grahana time we need to perform japa by taking bath same rule is here, as the sun changes its state..